# Set Input Value to Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, input

Let's say I have a variable called x in javascript. How can I set the value of a text input (HTML) to that variable? For example:

The value of the input will now be Swag

```
<input type="text" value="Swag" />
```

But if I want the value to be a javascript variable? How do I do? Something like this? (I am just guessing, trying to make my point clear)

```
<input type="text" value="variable.x" />
```

Comment: plain js or with jquery

Comment: You can't do that.  Instead, look at binding systems like Knockout.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can set it in your javascript code like:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" value="Swag" />

<script>
    var test = "test";
    document.getElementById("myInput").value = test;
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Soo will the value of the input with this method be "test" or "swag"?

Answer (score 2):

This is a better solution and will probably avoid confusion for newbies...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<h1>Input and Display Message</h1>

<p>Enter a message</p>

  <input type="text" id="msg" ><br>
  <button onclick="displayMessage()">Click me</button>


<p id="showinputhere"></p>

<script>
function displayMessage(){
    let themsg = document.getElementById("msg").value;
    if (themsg){
        document.getElementById("showinputhere").innerHTML = themsg;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("showinputhere").innerHTML = "No message set";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```