# Displaying a string value in a JSP

Tags: java, html, string, forms, jsp

I am getting value of Total Price in the 1st Line of code and I am able to see the value written also in 6th line of this code, BUT when I am trying to send this value to another JSP in a form in 5th line of this code then I am getting null value. I know its a bad idea to write scriptlets in JSP but I am learning JSF, for time being kindly guide me how can I get value string "s" in billing.jsp?

```html
    <div>Total price: $<span class="total-cart"></span></div> // Here I am 
    getting total price value lets say $10

    <%String s="<span class=total-cart></span>";%> // here I stored the 
    total price $10 in a string "s"

      <form name="billing" action="billing.jsp">        <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<%=s%>"/> // Here Unable to get 
 // the s value $10 and thus unable to send this $10 to another JSP
 // billing.jsp
    <input type="submit"/> Order now <%=s%>// But here I am getting value$10 

  </div>
      </form>
```

Billing.jsp

---

```html
 <%

String price=""; 

 price=request.getParameter("price").toString();
out.println(price);  // Here I want to display the value of string "s" that 
// is total price $10 but getting null value

 %>
```

Kindly help me where I am wrong

Comment: Maybe you forgot to quote the `value` parameter in your `input` tag (e.g. `value="<%=s%>"`).

Comment: no still getting nothing

Comment: why are you putting `html` tag i.e `String s="<span class=total-cart></span>";`  in `s` and from where did you got your `price` ?

Comment: I am getting price from this "<span class=total-cart></span>" ....little bit surprise but yes

Comment: That `price` is generated dynamically.. so how it would be  available in your `input` tag . ?

Comment: ok so how can I take the price data in a form to billing.jsp ?

Comment: That price is generated by some `script` so you can assign that value to `input` type using that `script` only .. for example check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059824/set-input-value-to-javascript-variable)

Comment: please see my question and help me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56454111/store-the-value-in-java-or-in-javascript-so-that-it-can-be-passed-to-another-jsp