# change variable value by Html input

Tags: javascript, html, input, user-input

I created a variable and give it 0
`let var = 0;`

I want to change variable value by html input.

`<input type="text" id="input" />`

How can I do that

Comment: please read the stackoverflow tour before posting such questions.

Comment: <p><?php echo $VAR; ?></p> this is read steps thanks

Comment: https://code-boxx.com/display-php-variables-in-html/ 

Read and check this step in this website page.

Comment: @kuldeepraj the question doesn't mention PHP at all, so that's not relevant.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones he is asking how to render variable in html

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones this exact way for html https://html.com/attributes/input-value/

Comment: https://html.com/attributes/input-value/

@Mohammed Zaky

Comment: @Mohammed Zaky This last for u :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059824/set-input-value-to-javascript-variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change javascript variable to value in html form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772051/change-javascript-variable-to-value-in-html-form-field) and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event#text_input_element has a working example

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" onchange="changeV()">
...

let v = 0;
var changeV = ()=>{
    v = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
}
```

****And there's a serious error in your code. "let var = 0;" "var" is a keyword predefined in javascript. Specifically, it is a keyword used in variable declaration. Do not use predefined keywords as variable names.

Comment: It doesn't work
I use if condition when variable = 0 show input. and if it more than it show all project.